# How to get data on text change and dropdown in an input?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I've an input box which has text field and a drop down. My intention to trigger data on text change in one method whereas for drop down another method. Below is the code for your reference.

```
const allList = [
    { id: "1", value: "Fruits" },
    { id: "2", value: "Vegetables" },
    { id: "3", value: "Grains" },
    { id: "4", value: "Milk" }
  ];

  const [itemList, setItemList] = useState(allList);

// Here I want to make trigger data for text change and drop down
const itemChanged = (e) => {
    if(e.keyPress) {
      console.log("Data Changed from key press.....", e.currentTarget.value);
    } else {
      console.log("Data Changed from Drop down.....", e.currentTarget.value);
    }
    
  };

<div className="select-with-search">
          <DataList
            list="itemListOptions"
            id="itemList"
            placeholder="Search/select items"
            data={itemList}
            onSelectionChange={itemChanged}
          ></DataList>
        </div>
```

Following is the DataList.js file

```
<input
        className="form-control cpselect"
        id={props?.id ?? ''}
        list={props?.list ?? ''}
        placeholder={props?.placeholder ?? ''}
        onChange={props?.onSelectionChange ?? ''}
        
      />
    <datalist key={props.id} id={props?.list ?? ''} >
        {props.data.map((d) => {
            return(
            <option key={d.id} id={d.id} value={d.value} ></option>
            );
        }
        )}
    </datalist>
```

What could be the best optimal solution?
Please refer to the codesandbox link --> https://codesandbox.io/s/quiet-cache-4ks1ml

Comment: Hello. Not sure I fully understand your question. Are you asking how to change the value of the `<input>` based on a change in the dropdown?

Comment: Hi @MatthewHerbst thanks for the response. I want to get data on text change and dropdown by putting condition in 'itemChanged', i.e if user types something that text change would be detected whereas if user selects anything from dropdown even that would also be detected

Comment: I looked at your codesandbox, I think I understand: you want to be able to tell if the change was from the user typing, or if the change was from the user selecting a value from the dropdown, is that correct?

Comment: Yes you got it... that is what expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detect by [inputType](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/InputEvent/inputType)

```
const itemChanged = (e) => {
    if (e.nativeEvent.inputType) {
      console.log("Data Changed from key press.....", e.currentTarget.value);
    } else {
      console.log("Data Changed from Drop down.....", e.currentTarget.value);
    }
};
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-wave-pntqnk?file=/src/Home.js:321-564)